# Nested Json respond jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I get a Json object like this

```
a:18:{s:19:"id_customer_address";s:6:"538767";s:10:"first_name";s:8:"Jhon";s:9:"last_name";s:6:"Milton";s:8:"address1";s:6:"St Avenue";s:8:"address2";s:3:"#238";s:8:"address4";s:10:"St. Patric";s:12:"near_streets";s:18:"";s:4:"city";s:11:"New Jersey";s:8:"postcode";s:5:"06700";s:5:"phone";s:10:"xxxxxxxx";s:11:"fk_customer";s:6:"471421";s:10:"fk_country";s:3:"157";s:26:"fk_customer_address_region";s:1:"9";s:18:"is_default_billing";s:1:"0";s:19:"is_default_shipping";s:1:"0";s:10:"created_at";s:19:"2017-08-18 12:08:06";s:10:"updated_at";s:19:"2017-08-22 15:33:35";s:7:"_locale";s:2:"es";}
```

And I try to get the data inside of that json, I would try something like this:

```
var nue = JSON.parse(address); 
var id = nue.id_customer_address; 
and 
var id = nue['id_customer_address'];
```

But any can't helps me, how can I get all the data?.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, you can check it here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: I don't know what is outputting this awful format, but I've seen a lot of questions asking about it. Google shows several of them too: https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=20&newwindow=1&ei=b-V5WoG2CcWdwASj6oCYCQ&q=a%3A18%3A%7Bs%3A19%3A%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=a%3A18%3A%7Bs%3A19%3A%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3750.3898.0.4015.2.2.0.0.0.0.114.205.1j1.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.oJ3oLzWGa6Y As said above, the format isn't JSON, so you cannot parse it as such. I'd suggest finding a parser from the source.

Comment: Thanks @MarkBenovsky

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thanks, Now I check how can ommit that way of response

Comment: That's PHP `serialize()` format, not JSON.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, in my php I had `$add->serialize()` and just only put `unserialize($add->serialize())` and that's all!

Comment: (1) Use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in your PHP code to generate JSON. Then the `JSON.parse` in your JavaScript code will be able to parse it. (2) `nue.id_customer_address` and `nue['id_customer_address']` mean exactly the same thing; if one doesn't work, the other won't either. (3) This has nothing at all to do with jQuery! (4) Learn how to debug JavaScript, e.g. with the [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). At the very least, the `JSON.parse` should have thrown an exception that you could view in the console.